# Nuget ошибка прокси

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

На работе, время от времени, приходится менять пароль.

Так вот, почему-то сейчас при попытке скачать пакет вылетает такая ошибка:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for
>   'Dapper.1.50.4' from source 'nuget.org'. An error occurred while
>   sending the request. The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy
>   Authentication Required.          0

Я подозреваю, что Nuget стучится со старыми учетными данными, так как спустя какое-то время моя учетка блокируется из-а N кол-ва попыток ввода неверного пароля. И началось это как раз после смены учетных данных.

Подскажите, в каком месте я могу актуализировать учетные данные или как сделать, что бы Nuget спросил меня и я ввел новые данные?

Поиск по Nuget выполняется упешно, а вот скачать не получается...

Comment: Актуализировать учетные данные - это скорее всего к админам прокси. А сам nuget умеет передавать реквизиты для аутентификации на прокси, вопрос в том, какой тип аутентификации на нем. Как вариант вот - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy

Comment: @defrag интернет у меня тоже через прокси. Когда учетные данные меняются, то например браузер их просит ввести по новой.

Comment: По идее, нужно как то заставить nuget спросить меня учетные данные.

Comment: По идее да. Но nuget не браузер, и навряд ли их спросит по такой аналогии. Может есть некая связь с IE или вижл студией, может из них можно повлиять. Но тут я хз.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, Nuget использует "Общие учетные данные", которые хранятся в "Диспетчер учетных данных".
Поменял там учетку и все заработало.